# Why is Room not using my pre-packaged/pre-populated database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm bundling a pre-populated database with my app, following the guidelines documented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate) under "Prepopulate from an app asset", but the most basic query returns zero results (when there should be 46 results).

Here's my database class:

```
@Database(
    entities = [CRSTitle::class],
    version = 2,
    exportSchema = false,
)
abstract class CRSDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun titleDao(): TitleDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: CRSDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): CRSDatabase {
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                return Room.databaseBuilder(context, CRSDatabase::class.java, CRSApp.databaseName)
                    .createFromAsset(CRSApp.databaseName)
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        Instance = it
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My DAO:

```
@Dao
interface TitleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM CRSTitle WHERE year = :year")
    suspend fun getAllTitles(year: Int): List<CRSTitle>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CRSTitle WHERE year = :year AND title_num_ = :titleNum")
    suspend fun getTitle(year: Int, titleNum: String): CRSTitle
}
```

and the entity:

```
data class CRSTitle(
    @PrimaryKey val Z_PK: Int,
    val index: Long,
    val year: Int,
    val title_num_: String,
    val title_text_: String,
    val editors_note: String?,
    val source_note: String?,
    val xref_note: String?,
)
```

`getAllTitles(2022)` returns zero results, when there should be 46.  Using the Device Explorer, I see my pre-packaged database has been copied to `/data/user/0/<my.package.id>/databases/` (and the size is correct).

But I **also** see the lock file `/data/user/0/<my.package.id>/cache/data/user/0/<my.package.id>/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb.lck`, which makes me believe that it's trying to read from a "default"(?) database that Room is creating on its own (which is found in `/data/data/<my.package.id>/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb`) but then there's also `/data/user/0/<my.package.id>/cache/Colorado_CRS.sqlite.lck`, which seems to refute that assertion.

I've been scouring the Room docs and what relevant SO posts I can find, but can't figure out what I might be missing/doing wrong. I can download/open the copied .sqlite file and see that there are, in fact, 46 results in the table for that query, so...what's going on?

Comment: WorkManager does have its own database, which is completely independent from your own (that's why they are two different files). What makes you think that is at all related?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not using WorkManager at all, so why is it there?

Comment: If it is there, you, or one of the libraries you are using, _is_ using it. You could look at your [dependency tree](https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree) to confirm that.

Comment: I would suspect that the issue may be that you are not waiting for the suspended thread to complete. You could check for this situation by adding the`.allowMainThreadQueries()` method to the methods invoked by the Room `databaseBuilder` and then running the query on the main thread (without suspend) if the results are then as expected you need to observe the result from the suspended thread. (this does assume that there are no exceptions causing the issue)